# How to compare values in Array based on given indexes range c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, indexing, compare

I would really appreciate if someone will help me.

How can i compare values of array based on given indexes and return newArray of indexes of the compared values.
I've an array like this

```
int val = {1,5,1,6,2,5,4,8,3};
```

Now on the above given array i want to compare values based on given range of indexes

```
int indexes = {4, 0, 5, 8};
```

based on the above given indexes i want to compare their values in the val array and return new array of that indexes but this time based on smallest value. Example the result i want

```
result = {0, 4, 8, 5}
```

0 for 1,
4 for 2,
8 for 3,
5 for 5.

Comment: Please try yourself first. It's better to ask if something fails, not for the whole answer unless it's something new

Comment: @kgzdev This is a something new for me because i can't find anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```cs
var result = indexes.OrderBy(i => val[i]).ToArray();
```

Edit: You need to be careful with your `indexes` array, because if you have an index there that does not exist in your main array, `val[i]` will throw an exception.